# Detecting missing drivers for Hyper-V Server 2012

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

Assume I installed Hyper-V Server 2012. Networking is working fine. The server is locked down, only RDP is enabled.  Enabling other ports may not be an option as the server is directly connected to the internet. As I understood it, Hyper-V Server 2012 is simply Windows Server 2012 with the Hyper-V role installed. No other roles are available.

Using only the tools available on the installed OS, how do I detect which drivers are missing?  In a full blown Windows, I would usually look at the device manager to spot any devices that are missing drivers. But that doesn't seem to be an option.

I have been looking to see if I can achieve this through PowerShell, but without any luck.

Comment: well with just the hyper-v role installed you can't really be missing a driver, if you were missing a driver the darn thing wouldn't boot.

Comment: Well, I have one installed which reports "no active network adapter".  The thing boots fine, just no network connectivity. So given that its the first time I'm running Windows Server 2012 Core, I'm curious how to diagnose driver issues in that flavor of Windows.

Comment: lol, since you are rdp'd into it I incorrectly figured your network would be good to go. Basically with w2k12 if its not in the box then microsoft doesn't support it, so unless you have an oem that supports your install you will be out of luck if you need support.

Comment: Just to make sure, it is the host experiencing problems, not a virtual machine inside hyper-v. I actually have several instances of Hyper-V server running, only one is failing with that error message.